# I fetch contact profile image from contact book but photo is stretched always

Tags: android, image, contacts, profile

I fetch photo but it is not looking good, it is stretched. I fetch the contact profile image by the below code. Please find attached image.

```
Bitmap photo = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(columnIndex)));
        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //contactIm.setImageBitmap(photo);
    if (photo == null) {
        /*String letter = gc.split_word(cName);
        TextDrawable drawable = gc.name_image(letter);
        contact_image.setImageDrawable(drawable);*/
    } else {
        contactIm.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
```

[image: This is image of one contact]

Comment: Did you try set scaleType center in xml?

Comment: No, scale type is not set.

Comment: I mean you try to set it in XML it will be not stretch like that

Comment: Yes, I checked but the same result is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openDisplayPhoto(contactId)));

public InputStream openDisplayPhoto(long contactId) {
     Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
     Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd =
             getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
         return fd.createInputStream();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

[image: After apply below code.]